# jQuery 1.9 - Internet Explorer 9 freezes after first $ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9

For a [dynamic page](http://www.habariwebcomponents.de/demo/ajaxstats.html), I use Ajax Long Polling and even with jQuery 1.9, Internet Explorer hangs after the first request.

The script code is based on the article [Simple Long Polling Example with JavaScript and jQuery](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery)

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
     (function poll(){
       $.ajax({ url: "ajaxstats.json", success: function(data){
         $("button.requests" ).empty().append(data.requests);
   }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 30000 });
     })();
   });
 </script>
```

The console shows no errors.

The IE network monitor immediately shows many requests to the `ajaxstats.json` resource with a **response time of < 1 ms** and a `304 (not modified)` response code. The response body is correct (JSON code).

The server code always delays the answer by 1000 milliseconds. And in Firefox, Firebug XHR log shows that every request takes around 1000 milliseconds, as expected.

The HTTP response code is different between Firefox and Internet Explorer:

- in Firefox: response code is `200 ok`
- in Internet Explorer 9, the response code is `304 (not modified)`

Is there a way to work around this IE problem?

Comment: any errors in the console? what about the http traffic?

Comment: @jbabey see my edit, I will update it with my findings in Firefox

Comment: Did you clear you cache? You are making a GET request which will cache the http response. Set the cache option to the ajax call if you want jQuery to add a cache breaking querystring parameter to the call.

Comment: on a side note, one of the comments on the linked article already covered this: "are you sure the timeout param in $.ajax works that way, i.e. to delay the next execution by at least 30 seconds? Because i think it just sets a maximum timeout for the call. When I tried it just now the function kept firing AFAICT as fast as it could loop."

Comment: @jbabey I guess this is as designed, I delay the response for exactly this reason - avoid overloading the client. In other words: the server controls when the next refresh of the page will happen.

Comment: @mjn yea, you just have to cachebust the ajax requests if your polling mechanism only exists on the server, as Corneliu answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting cache param to false, if set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
     (function poll(){
       $.ajax({ url: "ajaxstats.json", success: function(data){
         $("button.requests" ).empty().append(data.requests);
   }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 30000, cache: false });
     })();
   });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `setTimeout` version on the article. The `timeout` option sets the timeout for the request, not the time to wait until the next request.

There's a [reply](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery#comment_147) to a comment from Lars, where the author suggests that.

Comment: +1 - the other answer works well too - hard to say for my which one is "the best"

Comment: In fact, I think you had two problems: one was getting a cached response, which was probably too fast and IE didn't seem to handle it properly, starting the next request right away. The other problem was the way you want your long polling to work: the way it is, it's not waiting 30 secs before the next request, what you could accomplish with the `setTimeout` version.

Comment: The idea is not to wait 30 sec before next request, but to keep the connection to the server open and call the poll function and restart the polling process (reopen connection), as soon as a success or error callback is executed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a good answer on why IE9 hangs other than the fact that IE9 is just slow.  It will intermittently take forever to call the callback of an ajax call.  Testing at work, I've seen the same ajax call against the same server take more than 5x the time in IE9 as it does in Firefox, even though the browsers are running on the same machine.

If you are building a real time app and have access to the actual server it is running on I highly recommend you use Socket.IO.  http://socket.io/  Originally it was built for node.js but there are server side implements now for most of the major languages.

The client library has this fall back order:

- WebSocket
- Adobe Flash Socket
- AJAX long polling
- AJAX multipart streaming
- Forever Iframe
- JSONP Polling

On the newer browsers you get true web socket performance, on those that don't support it you get long polling for free but you get to just treat it as a web socket using the same clean Socket.IO interface.

Comment: Just a reminder. If your are using some SO with library caching as Windows Vista and above, when using a program you ever use, you will get a performance boost, because the required libraries are already cached into memory.